# Can custom map tiles be consumed via ArcObjects within my ArcGIS 10 Desktop AddIn?

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, arcgis, arcobjects

Can I programmatically consume and render custom map tiles in ArcMap via our ArcGIS 10 Desktop AddIn?

The AddIn is built using the ArcObjects SDK for C#/.NET and ArcGIS 10.  Pulling and rendering map tiles is NOT the AddIn's primary function.  But we would definitely like to implement this feature if it can be done.

More specifics:

- I received a tip that the ITiledMapServer2 interface is involved but it is unclear to me, and there is a dearth of info in ArcObjects docs regarding this task.  The equivalent class within the ArcGIS for Flex API is TiledMapServiceLayer, but again this is an ArcMap AddIn in the desktop space, not a web app.
- We have in-house software to generate our own tiles in the same zoom, tile Y, tile X tiling scheme akin to the Google maps JS/Flash APIs.
- We are using Apache to serve the map tiles and thus are currently not using ArcGIS Server in any way (i.e. authoring the tiles, publishing as an ArcGIS Server map service, etc).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a little searching for folks, the question / answers are [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2217/736).